# What happens if you're defeated in an ambush?

Tags: final-fantasy-13-2

The tutorial text describing the Mog Clock says that if you let the timer into the red, you're immediately forced into battle and *that if you lose that battle you don't get the retry option*.  What actually happens in that case?

In most games I would expect you to get kicked back to the title screen, but with autosaving (and being able to save manually almost anywhere) that doesn't seem like much of a punishment here, but it must do something bad or there would be no reason to implement this.  I'm afraid to try, personally, without knowing what will happen.

Comment: You should save, then run to somewhere else and die and see which spot you respawn in. I would imagine it should kick you back to your last save point.

Comment: @DavidYell - I'm still early enough in the game (got a copy through the promo grant but it only showed up over the weekend) that it's actually a bit difficult to die on purpose, the baddies are so weak I think the AI could solo them before I'd die.  I'd idle as SYN but I don't have the role yet.

Comment: Oh I see. I tend to find a huge boss and get him to kill me, like the Giant Flan in Sunleth Waterscape or the Giant Ci'eth in Academy!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not quite sure I understand it either. I've lost a couple battles with the retry option locked, and instead it just kicks you back to where you were (just like the retry option). I think the only difference is that you essentially lose the battle, losing any items you may have used and that's it. Not a huge deal, so don't worry too much if you fail. :)

Comment: If this happens, is the monster still there?  (Also, welcome to gaming.SE, hope to see you stick around!)

Comment: Sorry, well if you haven't figured it out already (as my post is a little late) if it's a random encounter, they'll disappear but any kind of boss fight or special monster like the ones on the Steppes seem to stay there. And thank you! :)

Comment: I have yet to actually lose an ambush, but I've noticed that regular loses do exactly that, so it's pretty curious to me why they even bothered...